# Displaying a random user with a shortcode

Tags: functions, shortcode, users

I'm trying to setup a shortcode to show a single random user each time the page is refreshed. I've been successful in displaying **all** users or a select user by the user ID.

Here is my shortcode as it is now:

```
//* Shortcode for getting users
function list_of_users( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'display' => 'all',
            'user' => '30'
        ),
        $atts
    ));

    switch ( $display ) {
        case 'all':
            $content = display_all_users();
            break;
        case 'single':
            $content = display_single_user( (int) $user );
            break;
        case 'rotate':
            $content = display_rotate_users();
            break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('staff', 'list_of_users');
```

---

Here's the function to display **all** users:

```
function display_all_users(){ 
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $users = get_users( $args );

    $html = '<ul class="staff">';
        foreach( $users as $user ){ 
            $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/author/'.$user_info->user_nicename.'" class="staff-image">';
            $html .= mt_profile_img( $user->ID, array('size' => '250x250','echo' => false));
            $html .= '</a>';
            $html .= '<div class="staff-info"><a href="'.get_home_url().'/author/'.$user_info->user_nicename.'" class="staff-name"><h2>'.$user->display_name.'</h2></a>';
            $html .= '<div class="service-certs">';
            $html .= get_field('certifications','user_'.$user->ID);
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '<p class="service-excerpt">';
            $html .= get_field('short_bio','user_'.$user->ID);
            $html .= '</p>';
            $html .= '<a href="'.get_home_url().'/author/'.$user_info->user_nicename.'" class="more-staff-bio">Read more from ' . $user_info->user_firstname . '</a></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>';
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

---

Here's the function to show a single user by ID:

```
function display_single_user( $user_id = 30 ){

    $html = '<div class="home-profile-image">';
    $html .=  mt_profile_img( $user_id, array('size' => '175x175','echo' => false));
    $html .= '</div><div class="home-short-bio">';
    $html .=  get_field('short_bio','user_'.$user_id);
    $html .= '</div><a href="'.get_home_url().'/our-team/" class="button">Read more staff bios</a>';

    return $html;
}
```

---

Where I'm stuck is to take the list of all users and then randomizing the user id to then use to display certain info. I would like to keep the output of the single user (above) for this random user...it's just a matter of how to get that random ID.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Pretty simple. Modify your existing code and instead of `'orderby' => 'ID'` you should be able to do `'orderby' => 'rand'`.

Comment: @GhostToast That was my original thought, however, the WP Codex leads me to believe that's not an option: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Comment: Plz pals am stil young in PHP and neither a pro in Wordpress. This is exactly what I have been looking for bt if am to use any of this examples, where do I "paste" it in my wordpress site?

Comment: My example is for a shortcode that I built. So everything got added to my theme's `function.php` so that I was able to use my shortcode in the page/post editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default WordPress allow only order ASC and DESC. However, you can use [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and the action `pre_user_query` to adjust the query (that is passed by reference) just like you want.

This is efficient because you get only one user, not all.

```
function my_user_by_rand( $ua ) {
  // remove the action to run only once
  remove_action('pre_user_query', 'my_user_rand');
  // adjust the query to use random order
  $ua->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login ASC', 'RAND()', $ua->query_orderby );
}

function display_random_user(){
  // add the filter
  add_action('pre_user_query', 'my_user_by_rand');
  // setup the query
  $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'user_login', 'order' => 'ASC', 'number' => 1
  );
  $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
  // run the query
  $user_query->query();
  // get the result
  $random = ! empty($user_query->results) ? array_pop($user_query->results) : FALSE;
  // just for debug
  print_r($random);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should get you a random user. Not tested.

```
function display_random_user(){ 
    $users = get_users();
    $user_info = get_userdata($users[array_rand($users)]->ID);
    // do stuff with info
}
```

[PHP: array_rand - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Comment: Thanks @GhostToast. I found another option that involved something like `shuffle($users);array_rand($users);foreach( $users as $user ){ //do stuff }unset($uid,$userID);` ...it seemed to work as well. Do you have any insight on which is a better solution?

Comment: well, `foreach` would imply you're doing this to more than one `$user`. We really just want to randomly select one from the deck and be done. You could still `shuffle()` before getting your `array_rand()`, which help to make the randomization more random probably.

Comment: Thanks. If there's no benefit to one way or the other, I'll stick with your solution...it seems more efficient.